# Numerical root finding for 5th degree polyomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

I have the equation $y^5 -ay -b=0$.

I need to get a solution whether numerical or analytical. I heard $5$th order polynomials are not solvable analytically, so how can I get the root numerically. Please guide me, I am new to numerical analysis.

Comment: I would suggest [Newton's method,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) which will give you successive approximations on the roots depending on the value of $a$.

Comment: What do we know about the coefficients $a,b$?  Are they real? nonzero? positive?

Comment: If you just need a numerical solution, typing the equation into Wolfram Alpha does the job. If you need to write some code that computes it, you should clarify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Numerical method**

The best suited numerical method is [newtons method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).

Here's the iteration

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{x_n^{~5}-ax_n-b}{5x_n^{~4}-a}\newcommand{\BR}{\operatorname{BR}}$$

Simply choose a guess for the solution of the equation and call it $x_0$ then using the above formula, calculate as many iterations you want, each iteration get's you closer to the actual value. (it's worth noting that if you made a bad guess, the formula might not converge)

**Analytic method**

We can express the solution of your equation analytically with the function $\BR(x)$ as the formula below<sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Solution_of_the_general_quintic)</sup>
$$\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{a}{5}}\cdot\BR\left(\frac b4\cdot\sqrt[4]{\frac{25}{a^5}}\right)$$

Where $\BR(x)$ is the inverse of $x^5+x$, this inverse has a taylor series of<sup>[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Series_representation)</sup>

$$\BR(x)=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{5k}{k}\dfrac{(-1)^ka^{4k+1}}{4k+1}$$